# Let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Prove that $Z(f)=\{p\in S:f(p)=0\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that I have to solve this problem indirectly and using the fact that the inverse image of open set is open.

> Theorem 4.3
>
> Let $S$ and $T$ be metric spaces and $E $ a subset of $S$. A function $f : E \rightarrow T$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if $f^{−1}(O)$ is open in $E$ for every open set $O \subset T $.

I just don’t know how start!

Thanks.

Comment: $Z(f)$ is the complement of the inverse image of the complement of $\{0\}$

Comment: I changed the title so that it is shorter and easier to read. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As $f^{-1}(T \backslash O)=E \backslash f^{-1}(O)$ you can first prove that the inverse image of a closed set is closed.

Then you can prove that $\{0\}$ is closed to conclude.